# How can I share sessions between Chrome and Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I am using PAW to test API routes on a local application. Access (at this stage) is granted via a session cookie which is generated when logging into the application via the site (in browser - specifically Chrome).

I can manually copy the session cookies into PAW from Chrome (and it works), but is tedious considering I need to do this daily.

Is there a way (like in Postman) to capture/intercept cookies from Chrome in PAW?

Comment: Hey @Chris sorry for the late answer. We're working on a nice Chrome extension for some time in December, that will perfectly fit your needs :)

Comment: Ok looking forward to that, thanks! If you add that as an answer, I will mark it solved. And once released, to keep this question accurate, update it to include the release of the Chrome extension.

Comment: Thanks! Will do for sure :)

Comment: May I ask, which year December please??

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Curious if there was an update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Micha Mazaheri's comment to the original question, Paw doesn't currently (2015-12-23) support sharing sessions between Chrome and itself.

A future update to the program may include it. Answer shall be edited to reflect said update.